# I can't debug local variables with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm testing Swift with Xcode 6.1.1. and i have loaded UICatalog project from Apple.
I can debug normally with Objective C in another projects, and with Swift can debug global objects but not LOCAL variables.

Are there special configurations in Xcode? Why can't debug it?

Comment: Where did you set your breakpoint? You need to set your breakpoint into the function of which local variables you want to inspect.

Comment: Hi @MariusFanu. Yes, I put breakpoint into the function where variable is defined. I do like with Objective-C, but with Swift I only can inspect properties of the object where function is defined.

Comment: Thanks Marius, suddenly it has begun normally

Answer (score 8):

In the project build settings change the `Optimization Level` under `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` for `Debug` configuration to `None [-Onone]`.

Comment: I don't know why they don't put these kind of things by default. Thanks